# Does truncating a counter column family have the same caveats as removing a single counter

Tags: cassandra

When truncating a Counter Column Family in Cassandra do the counters suffer from the same limitations as just removing a single column or row?

Will I have to drop the column family and recreate it to completely clear it out or should I be fine truncating it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is the same: if you are doing simultaneous deletes or truncates and increments, the result is undefined.

The issue is that delete is effectively setting the counter value to zero.  Truncate is setting all counter values to zero.  The 'set' operation does not commute with the 'inc' operation, so a mixture of simultaneous operations gives unpredictable results.

If you aren't doing increments or can pause them, then it is perfectly safe doing a truncate.  There is no need to drop the column family.  If you cannot stop the increments then it depends on your client.  Dropping the column family will cause the client to fail until it is recreated - if the client can survive those errors and then continue that might work.  But the best would be to temporarily pause the increments.

Comment: Excellent answer thank you! I didn't realise that as long as you stop the increments then removing the counters will be okay! I also though that once a counter was deleted you couldn't use it again!